# Add editable to bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I try to use bootstrap table editable. In my jsp page I have:

```
<div class="row mystyle" >
  <div class="col-md-10">
   <table id="mytable" class="table table-hover" id="table-pagination"
                       data-url="data.json" 
                       data-toggle="table"
                       data-pagination="true"
                       data-show-pagination-switch="true"
                       data-sort-order="desc" 
                       data-show-export="true" 
                       data-search="true" 
                       data-show-toggle="true"  
                       data-show-refresh="true" 
                       data-show-columns="true"
                       data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]">

      <thead>
        <tr>
         <th data-field="id" data-align="center">id</th>
         <th data-field="type" data-align="center">type</th>
         <th data-field="quantity" data-align="right" data-sortable="true">cost</th> 
        </tr>
      </thead>
  </table>
</div>
```

and my table is shown great. Now I want to add the [editable method](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-editable). I added the `<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-table-editable.js"></script>` and then how ? It isn't clear to me (I am newbie..), how I continue..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need add the `bootstrap-editable.js` file, because our extension is based on `x-editable` like the example: [source](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table-examples/blob/master/extensions/editable.html#L14).

There are other examples maybe can help you:
[demo1](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html#extensions/editable.html),
[demo2](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html),
[demo3](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#issues/986.html),
and the [docs](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/extensions/#table-editable).

Answer (score 1):

call `editable` by selecting your table with jquery:

```
var options = {};
$("#mytable").editable(options);
```

For the full specs and options list, check [here](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html#editable)

Comment: ok.. what i have to add to get the result of this http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#extensions/editable.html

Comment: I load the data with `data-url="data.json" ` how I add all the classes?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, here is a Reactstrap table with cell-edit capabilities. See https://github.com/msb1/reactstrap-functional-table

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple to use X-editable plugin if you want editable fields in Bootstrap Table.

You simply just have to set  `data-editable="true"` to the fields you want in edit mode.

If you are passing array of object for colums them add this property to that particular column ex `{"field": 'age' ,"editable":true`

All you have to make sure that you are using a stable version of the CDN.

**IMPLEMENTATION:**

First make a file and write this code there and simply import it.

```
/**
 * @author zhixin wen
 * extensions: https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable
 */

!function ($) {

    'use strict';

    $.extend($.fn.bootstrapTable.defaults, {
        editable: true,
        onEditableInit: function () {
            return false;
        },
        onEditableSave: function (field, row, oldValue, $el) {
            return false;
        },
        onEditableShown: function (field, row, $el, editable) {
            return false;
        },
        onEditableHidden: function (field, row, $el, reason) {
            return false;
        }
    });

    $.extend($.fn.bootstrapTable.Constructor.EVENTS, {
        'editable-init.bs.table': 'onEditableInit',
        'editable-save.bs.table': 'onEditableSave',
        'editable-shown.bs.table': 'onEditableShown',
        'editable-hidden.bs.table': 'onEditableHidden'
    });

    var BootstrapTable = $.fn.bootstrapTable.Constructor,
        _initTable = BootstrapTable.prototype.initTable,
        _initBody = BootstrapTable.prototype.initBody;

    BootstrapTable.prototype.initTable = function () {
        var that = this;
        _initTable.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));

        if (!this.options.editable) {
            return;
        }

        $.each(this.columns, function (i, column) {
            if (!column.editable) {
                return;
            }

            var editableOptions = {}, editableDataMarkup = [], editableDataPrefix = 'editable-';

            var processDataOptions = function(key, value) {
              // Replace camel case with dashes.
              var dashKey = key.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function($1){return "-"+$1.toLowerCase();});
              if (dashKey.slice(0, editableDataPrefix.length) == editableDataPrefix) {
                var dataKey = dashKey.replace(editableDataPrefix, 'data-');
                editableOptions[dataKey] = value;
              }
            };

            $.each(that.options, processDataOptions);

            var _formatter = column.formatter;
            column.formatter = function (value, row, index) {
                var result = _formatter ? _formatter(value, row, index) : value;

                $.each(column, processDataOptions);

                $.each(editableOptions, function (key, value) {
                    editableDataMarkup.push(' ' + key + '="' + value + '"');
                });

                return ['<a href="javascript:void(0)"',
                    ' data-name="' + column.field + '"',
                    ' data-pk="' + row[that.options.idField] + '"',
                    ' data-value="' + result + '"',
                    editableDataMarkup.join(''),
                    '>' + '</a>'
                ].join('');
            };
        });
    };

    BootstrapTable.prototype.initBody = function () {
        var that = this;
        _initBody.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.apply(arguments));

        if (!this.options.editable) {
            return;
        }

        $.each(this.columns, function (i, column) {
            if (!column.editable) {
                return;
            }

            that.$body.find('a[data-name="' + column.field + '"]').editable(column.editable)
                .off('save').on('save', function (e, params) {
                    var data = that.getData(),
                        index = $(this).parents('tr[data-index]').data('index'),
                        row = data[index],
                        oldValue = row[column.field];

                    $(this).data('value', params.submitValue);
                    row[column.field] = params.submitValue;
                    that.trigger('editable-save', column.field, row, oldValue, $(this));
                });
            that.$body.find('a[data-name="' + column.field + '"]').editable(column.editable)
                .off('shown').on('shown', function (e, editable) {
                    var data = that.getData(),
                        index = $(this).parents('tr[data-index]').data('index'),
                        row = data[index];
                    
                    that.trigger('editable-shown', column.field, row, $(this), editable);
                });
            that.$body.find('a[data-name="' + column.field + '"]').editable(column.editable)
                .off('hidden').on('hidden', function (e, reason) {
                    var data = that.getData(),
                        index = $(this).parents('tr[data-index]').data('index'),
                        row = data[index];
                    
                    that.trigger('editable-hidden', column.field, row, $(this), reason);
                });
        });
        this.trigger('editable-init');
    };

}(jQuery);
```

Then add this cdn to your file as well, just after import of this first file.

```
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js"></script>
```

**Hope it works.**